# Как использовать один скрипт php для обработки нескольких форм?

Tags: php, form

Я думаю, что вопрос очень лёгкий для знающих. Но мне как незнающему php не получается додуматься.

На сайте есть несколько стандартных форм. Письма с этих форм должны быть разными, что бы понимать с какой формы пришли данные. Я всегда делал отдельный php на каждую форму, что уверен неправильно ).

Как использовать один php на все формы? 
Указывать name на input:submit и через if обрабатывать?

Код php:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = '';



$mail_message = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Заявка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Заявка с формы "Перезвоните мне"</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>E-mail: ' .$email. '</li>
        <li>Телефон: ' .$tel. '</li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>';

$headers = 'From: ' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . "\r\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$mail = mail($to, 'Заказ', $mail_message, $headers);
```

Формы такого вида:

```
                <form action="" method="POST" class="calculate-form">
                    <input type="tel" name="tel" id="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" class="input calculate-input calculate-input--phone"
                        required="">
                    <input type="text" name="text" id="" placeholder="сколько м2 ?" class="input calculate-input calculate-input--area"
                        required="">
                    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn calculate-btn">
                </form>
```

Обработчик:

```
jQuery('.calculate-form').submit(function(e) {

    var $form = jQuery(this);

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function() {

        successWindow.addClass("popup-success__wrapper--active");
        $form[0].reset();
        console.log('success');
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('fail');
    });
    //отмена действия по умолчанию для кнопки submit
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Указывать name на input:submit и через if обрабатывать

Comment: А как должна выглядеть конструкция с if? 
Функцию  $mail = mail($to, 'Заказ', $mail_message, $headers); я запихиваю внутрь if?

Comment: Внутри if будет только присвоение значение $to. Вообще есть хорошее правило - не повторяться. Если ты видишь что 4 раза повторяешь один и тот же код, значит программа у тебя плохая, надо переписать.

Comment: Добавь скрытый инпут, в котором будет заголовок страницы и передавай его в письмо

Comment: Просто добавьте скрытый `input` с типом формы, а в скрипте обработчике поставьте переключатель определяющий какой обработчик задействовать.